# How do I force new windows to open on the currently active monitor

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

To me it seems that GNOME is opening the windows on a random monitor. How can I tell GNOME that it should always open a window on the currently active monitor (the monitor with the mouse)?

My gdm3 version is 42.0.

gnome-shell version is 42.9.